# Sound stopped working in Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, alsa

After years without an issue with ALSA, sound stopped working.

My system:

```
[root@myArch jm]# uname -a
Linux myArch 4.2.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 3 19:08:23 CEST 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
```

My card:

```
[root@myArch jm]# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf2620000 irq 30
```

The driver:

```
[root@myArch jm]#  lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_conexant    20480  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_intel          28672  3
snd_hda_codec          94208  3 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           45056  4 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                77824  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
snd                    57344  14 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

A test with a wav file. No sound.

```
[jm@myArch downloads]$ aplay tst.wav 
Playing WAVE 'tst.wav' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Stereo
```

How alsamixers looks:

[image: alsamixer]
Thanks,

Comment: 1. What happens if you feed a .wav file to `aplay`? 2. Are you running `pulseaudio`? If so, what happens if you feed a .wav file to `paplay`? 3. What do you see if you run `alsamixer`?

Comment: No, I don't use pulseaudio. Please check the edit above

Comment: Several channels in alsamixer are muted. Try navigating to them (left/right arrow keys) and unmuting them (M key). (A channel is muted if the letters under its level are `MM`; it's unmuted if they're `OO` and highlighted.)

Comment: Solved. For any reason the scrip I used `amixer set Master mute` is working, but the opposite `amixer set Master unmute` doesn't work. I had to use `amixer set Speaker unmute` to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happened with me yesterday, I tried:

```
alsactl init
```

and it started working. I think there is some issue with power manager which stops sound when some condition triggers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is just because the sound is muted you have MM above headphone and speaker both mute 
type n,p or arrow keys to move between, type m to unmute